# insert oracle table using DateTimePicker value

Tags: vb.net, oracle, types, datetimepicker

Setting of nls_date_format: MM/DD/YY

Setting format of DateTimePicker: DateTimePickerFormat.Custom

As I know, date format is just used to display the date information, doesnot affect to storage of it in database.

However, I cannot insert date into table with below query statements

```
query = "INSERT INTO tuser (objectID, userID, userName, password, birthday) values (urObjID.nextval,'" + txtUserID.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim + "','" + dtpBirthday.Value + "')" 'Insert directly Date value from DateTimePicker
```

and

```
query = "INSERT INTO tuser (objectID, userID, userName, password, birthday) values (urObjID.nextval,'" + txtUserID.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim + "','" + dtpBirthday.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "')" 'Insert string value with format dd/MM/yyyy
```

But can insert date into table with below queries

```
query = "INSERT INTO tuser (objectID, userID, userName, password, birthday) values (urObjID.nextval,'" + txtUserID.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim + "','" + dtpBirthday.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "')" 'Insert string value with format dd-MMM-yyyy
```

and

```
query = "INSERT INTO tuser (objectID, userID, userName, password, birthday) values (urObjID.nextval,'" + txtUserID.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtUserName.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtPassword.Text.Trim + "',TO_DATE('" + dtpBirthday.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yy") + "'))" 'Insert date value using TO_DATE function
```

Is there any differences between above statements that make the query work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use none of your statements, use parameters and bind variables.

```
query = "INSERT INTO tuser (objectID, userID, userName, password, birthday) values (urObjID.nextval, :userID, :userName, :password, :birthday)" 

cmd.CommandText = query 
cmd.Parameters.Add("userID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = txtUserID.Text.Trim()
cmd.Parameters.Add("userName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim()
cmd.Parameters.Add("password", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim
cmd.Parameters.Add("birthday", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = dtpBirthday.Value
```